# Sum of Selected rows from column using pentaho report designer

Tags: mysql, sql, report, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I'm using `Pentaho Report Designer (PRD) 3.8.`
My data structure is like this

```
id| name  |value |
1 | Jack  | 200  |
2 | Will  | 300  |
3 | Smith | 400  |
4 | Jack  | 500  |
```

Now the problem is that I want to get `sum` for `column Value` with only `selected rows`.
Is there any methods like

```
IF([name]='Jack' then sum([value]))
```

so value of sum is `700`.

I need the `sum` value in `formula` `not in query` because some name values are dummy values too.

Comment: Is that pseudo-SQL in your request or that's about SQL Server?

Comment: its sql in pentaho report designer

Comment: how are you populating these dummy names if not from your table?

Comment: dummy names are from temporary table generated

Answer (score 0):

Try `CASE`

```
SEELCT
SUM(CASE WHEN `name` ='jack' THEN `value` ELSE 0 END)
FROM `table`
```

Comment: i can't use sql cause some name values are dummy not used from table.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `SELECT SUM(value) FROM my_table WHERE name = 'jack'` would return the correct result. I don't know Pentaho but, presumably it could access a VIEW constructed along these lines.

Comment: some name values are dummy values too not from table

Answer (score 0):

How to use Select sum within a Select. For Example

```
SELECT 
  aa,
  bb,
  part_no
  Select sum (Unit_cost) as Cost_total 
  from COST_TABLE
  where part_no = det_table.Part_no
  Sale-TOT
FROM Det_table
WHERE status = 'o'
GROUPED BY Part_no
```

Note : There are Multiple Entries of Part Number in COST_TABLE